# Create table dynamically with MySQL command in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to create table dynamically and fill it with random numbers, but when execute code, MySQL throw an error about syntax.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //gameSession is int, i tried use Parameters.AddWithValue but still have same problem.
            MySqlCommand dice = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO "+gameSession.ToString()+" (Dice1,Dice2) Values (@dice1,@dice2)", myConnection);


            Random dice1 = new Random();
            dice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dice1", dice1.Next(1, 7));
            Random dice2 = new Random();
            dice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dice2", dice2.Next(1, 7));
            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            dice.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near INSERT INTO '7571877 ...

Comment: What is `7571877`? Is that an actual table? The correct syntax is `INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] ...`

Comment: Let me guess. One session one table? It looks like poor design

Comment: Yes, its table name.

Comment: why does gameSession.ToString() have a single quote in position 0

Comment: And you guess right :) i need one table for every session.

Comment: that is true @gustavodidomenico but unrelated to error message (though related to question title)

Comment: Expanding on the thoughts of my learned colleagues, why a separate table per session? You're defeating a main reason for which relational databases exist. Create a `Sessions` table that's contains a field `SessionId`

Comment: it is full error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '9498581 (Dice1,Dice2) Values (4,4)' at line 1"}

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl `If you are creating tables on the fly in your application, you have missed some fundamentals about database design. In a relational database, the set of tables and columns are supposed to be constant. They may change with the installation of new versions, but not during run-time. `

Comment: remove the single quote before the table name. In fact remove all single quotes. Then, learning how to do it, don't create tables on the fly like this. You will curse yourself later for doing so. Use a common table for everyone

Comment: I create online backgammon game , so i need separate table for each  game table.

Comment: no you don't need one. You think you need one. Let's say you wanted maximum performance of game-play analysis. That would be achieved super fast with one table. With infinite number of tables: Exhaustingly slow to implement and in performance once achieved

Comment: Instead of all of these tables why not just use a single table and save the session with the scores to it. The scores then can be retrieved by the session.

Comment: You do not need to create tables at runtime. If you think so, then pick up a book on database design. Anyway, see [9.2 Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html): _"Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits."_. Also, your use of the Random class is going to generate the same two numbers quite often.

Comment: I supposed there is no way to create table dynamically. I think i should think about another way to solve this problem and use session,Dice values in fields.

Comment: Perhaps after a few tens of thousands of rows in the table, you can archive it out. Dog it. But to pollute your system with jillions of tables like this, yikes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major reason you have an error in your syntax is that the table is not quoted.  Check out the [MySQL manual for identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) (which includes table names).

Just like you can't really use numbers by default to represent variables, you can't do the same for tables without escaping the identifiers.  A couple solutions for you would be to prefix the table name with a letter or to use a single table.

**Answering the question in your title:**

You can [create a table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) if it doesn't exist using the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause.  The SQL would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name IF NOT EXISTS (
    dice1 INTEGER,
    dice2 INTEGER
);
```

If you insist on going down this route, you should create your table names with a standard prefix letter:

```
"s" + gameSession.ToString()
```

> Be warned, having a separate table for each session does complicate your database maintenance needs, particularly for dealing with abandoned sessions.  It's a lot easier to remove rows in a single table than find all tables that are abandoned.

Another serious concern has to do with database security.  When building an application against a database, it is far better to only grant insert and update privileges to a user than it is to grant them the ability to create and drop any table in your database.  Since the table names are dynamically created, you can't really maintain per-table privileges easily.  If this is web facing you are opening yourself up to some serious liability for very little gain.

**Answering the need:**

A better design is to create a single table with a session id.  Otherwise, you will have any number of tables with one record each.  You would create the table once like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DiceRolls IF NOT EXISTS (
    session INTEGER,
    dice1 INTEGER,
    dice2 INTEGER
);
```

Your inserts would only need to change a little bit:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //gameSession is int, i tried use Parameters.AddWithValue but still have same problem.
        MySqlCommand dice = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO DiceRolls (Session, Dice1,Dice2) Values (@session,@dice1,@dice2)", myConnection);

        dice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", gameSession);
        Random dice1 = new Random();
        dice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dice1", dice1.Next(1, 7));
        Random dice2 = new Random();
        dice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dice2", dice2.Next(1, 7));
        if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            myConnection.Open();
        }
        dice.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This makes clean up a lot easier as you can batch job something that deletes everything that isn't a current session.

Comment: So i change my way to use session as field in my program, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your **table name**. Make sure table name is correct, then use this function:

```
void InsertDiece(string connectionString, string tableName, int count)
{
    var commandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO `{0}` (Dice1, Dice2) Values (@dice1, @dice2)", tableName);
    var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Milliseconds);
    using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dice1", random.Next(1, 7));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dice2", random.Next(1, 7));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: correct. This fails: `create table 93827 (i int not null);` while this succeeds `create table X93827 (i int not null);` ... plus his insert statement should not have single quotes regardless

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{0} (Dice1, Dice2) Values (1, 1)' at line 1

Comment: @zex_rectooor have you provided name for table? what is name of the table? also make sure you have added `String.Format` part which I forgot at first edition :P