# MySQL systax error in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I got error `"you have an error in your SQL systax.."` and I don't know where the error is. Anyone?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    string sql = "CREATE TABLE DiceRolls IF NOT EXISTS (session INTEGER, dice1 INTEGER, dice2 INTEGER);";
    string connString = "Server=localhost"+";database=3ddatabase"
        + ";port=3306" + ";User Id=root" +  ";password=";
   // string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;password=;";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is probably the semicolon at the end of the statement.  In addition `session` is a keyword (so it is a bad choice for a column name), but it probably shouldn't be causing a syntax problem.

Comment: @Văn Học please refer this link it might help you to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154674/create-table-dynamically-with-mysql-command-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error is in your mysql command.

You have

```
CREATE TABLE DiceRolls IF NOT EXISTS (session INTEGER, dice1 INTEGER, dice2 INTEGER);
```

When it should be `IF NOT EXISTS` then table_name:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DiceRolls (session INTEGER, dice1 INTEGER, dice2 INTEGER);
```